# Java android программирование. С чего начать, не зная ничего?

Tags: java, android, книги

Доброго времени суток, дорогие пользователи. Я только недавно начал увлекаться программированием (начал с JS) и понял, что это то, что мне нравится. Сейчас меня очень заинтересовало программирование под Андроид (сам имею ХТЦ Вайлдфайр, слабая модель и нормальных программ на него не очень много). И поэтому у меня появился вопрос. С чего можно конкретно начать программирование под андроид? Насколько я понял, самый легкий и практичный вариант - именно Джава. Но знания у меня полностью отсутствуют. Подскажите, с чего можно начать и где об этом прочитать? Заранее благодарю :)

P.S. желательно с практическими примерами

Comment: Вот отличный ресурс: [Разработка под Android](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ты правильно понимаешь, что начинать надо с **JAVA**. 
При устройстве потом на работу тебя будут тестировать одним из двух вариантов:

- если есть техлид (а это будет джавист с опытом от 3-5 до ... лет), т.е. будешь работать под его управлением, то будут тебя тестить по **знаниям Джава** и не так уж по знанию SDK Android. Так что желательно после прочтения книги (или прохождения курса) по Java пройти сертификацию по Java (для себя - не обязательно сертификат получать). Тут важно понимать **ООП** и как ты его используешь при написании приложений, чтобы не было "**говнокода**". В вопросах с Андроидом очень важно понимать как работать с **потоками** и что такое **процесс** и **стэк**;
- если техлида нет, а есть менеджер проекта, то скорее всего важны будут уже **имеющиеся программы** написанные тобою и вполне нормальный вариант, если дадут решить какое-то тестовое **задание** - к примеру в домашних условиях какую-то фичу на Андроиде сделать.

Желательно также учесть несколько моментов:

1. учить версию Java SE 6 (материала море, думаю найдутся те, кто лучше меня посоветуют где копать);
2. по Android (книги на англ. конечно свежее контент имеют ...) на русском знаю из нормальных две книги (потоки в них не расписаны, так что гугл/хабр/книги-на-англ.):

   - для начинающих [Программирование для мобильных устройств](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6573933/);
   - посерьёзнее [Разработка приложений для Android](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6227194/);
3. конечно юзаем раздел на Хабре [Разработка под Android](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/page1/). Там достают море подводных камней !!!
4. спрашиваем на [http://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). Так сложилось, что там самые большие запасы инфы по разработке на Андроид.
5. спрашиваем на [http://androidforums.ru](http://androidforums.ru/Obsuzhdenie-i-reshenie-problem-f8.html). На нашем языке, но интерфейс форума ... :)
6. исходники, если надо, берём в открых источниках: [http://code.google.com](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:Android), [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/repo/all?name=android) и конечно [github.com](https://github.com/search?type=Code&language=Java&q=android&repo=&langOverride=&x=22&y=18&start_value=1)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развернутый ответ. Как понимаю, по джава книги на русском есть, а вот под андроид лучше юзать англ.? Если кто-то знает, дайте хороший материал на Java SE 6. Опыта программирования нету. что-то для чайника.

Comment: по видеокурсам по Java:
1. мне понравился видео-курс: http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=928258
он же - http://teachpro.ru/course2d.aspx?idc=5049
2. на http://rutracker.org/ есть много (очень много) видео курсов по Java) ...

В JAVA книгах (когда цель - разработки по Андроид) мало смысла читать разделы про: Graphics User Interface, Swing, AWT.

оффтоп: по книгам, вот подумываю на книжный рынок сездить какую-то старую книжку прикупить :) Намекаю на то, что можно и старую книгу взять ...

Comment: Сейчас сам изучаю джаву по книге Ноутона и Шилдта "Java 2. Наиболее полное руководство". Очень даже неплохо.

Comment: @mikillskegg спасибо! Щас глянем...
@redsky Почитал коменты, пишут, что лажа!

Comment: ещё такой вопрос. Что за Java 1 и Java 2???

Comment: По Java мне посоветовали книгу - К.Арнольд, Д.Гослинг - Язык программирования Java. Вот намереваюсь почитать её ... Есть в электроном виде.
@vendetta8247 ВАЖНО заметить, что в комментах жалуются в основном на звук, а не содержание! Мне звук вполне пошёл. Послушать можно на любом из уроков тут: http://teachpro.ru/course2d.aspx?idc=5049 Мне понравилось как она объясняет. Про её профессионализм читал только хорошие отзывы.
Но можно поискать и ещё :)
 Кратенько про версии: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_Java

Comment: @redsky Хорошо, если советуете, посмотрю, ибо видеоуроки - очень хорошая штука, как мне кажется!  Уже скачал, будем смотреть

Comment: @vendetta8247 Всё, что до раздела "Базовые конструкции языка JAVA" - немного нудновато, но просмотреть желательно. Заниматься переводом в разные системы измерения мне на практике не приходилось :)
И так смотрите всё до раздела "Введение в апплеты" (сам раздел пропускаем) и потом всё до "Работаем с GUI" (этот раздел и всё, что после считаю не нужным в нашем контексте). Лично я по ходу печатал у себя в Eclipse всё то, что она печатала ... (тафтология вышла :) )

Answer (score 4):

Всё таки всегда лучше использовать [родной сайт по разработке под андроид](http://developer.android.com/index.html)