# Java Для мобильной разработки

Tags: mobile-development, java

Здравствуйте. Хочу начать изучать java для мобильной разработки,но не знаю с чего начать.
На пример для php нужно локальный сервер(xampp,wampp...)редактор итд
А что конкретно нужно для java ? рредактор/компилятор/интерпритатор/сервет итд

Спасибо заранее

Comment: вы про java-me или java-android ?

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего в 2014 году под мобильной разработкой вы имеете в виду Android.

Посмотрите ответы на [аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/46037/java-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE).

Comment: Самое то! Спасибо