# Android - разработка, основные особенности и подводные камни [Java];

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток!
Сейчас активно изучаю java, и хочется что нибудь на своем смартфоне запустить(Тот же HW);
Хотелось бы узнать, с чего следует начать разработку под андроид? Если не трудно напишите краткий план или скиньте полезности библиотеки, фреймворки, доки и прочее. Все что пригодится. Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8+android   ...........http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/46037/java-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A1-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE

Comment: Да, я понимаю что вопрос затертый в пыль. Но сейчас 2016 г. И хотелось бы получить более свежую информацию, спасибо.

Comment: Камнями не закидывайте, дам человеку путь, по которому сам шел))) Все равно как показала статистика 9 из 10 дропают. Итак чтобы стать андроид девом для начала тебе понадобятся базовые знания джавы -> http://kostin.ws/java/ после этого курса углуби знания о java колекциях. Этого тебе хватит на первое время. Дальше на ютубе есть канал startandroid там ты сможешь получить базовые знанияю по андроиду. Дальше тебе в помощь твоя любознательность, настойчивость и гугл! И помни золотое правило, любую проблему которую ты не нагуглил на русском с 95% вероятностью нагуглишь на англ. Так что учи англиский

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Android. Программирование для профессионалов. 2-е издание 2016 г.](http://www.piter.com/collection/all/product/android-programmirovanie-dlya-professionalov-2-e-izdanie-2)

Для начала рекомендую, даже по Material Design глава есть.