# С чего начать разрабатывать программу?

Tags: java, text, project

Еще ни разу не смог написать полноценно крупную программу и по этому не знаю с чего начать (Еще нет опыта в реальной работе). Изучаю java уже порядка 2 лет и за это время хорошо понял основы, но теперь когда я захотел заняться реальными проектами то возникает такая ситуация. Разработку программ я всегда начинал с написание программы(это работает только с простыми программами но НЕ с проектами). где то читал что программу надо начинать с изучения предметной области, выделение главной задачи и разбор по мелким, проектирование(в UML) а после написание самой программы, но так ли это? подскажите как и с чего начинать писать программу(пример заметки(пустое поле где размещены заметки разных типов)) в наше время?(тот метод который я описал работал лет так 10 назад)

Comment: с постановки задачи

Comment: ненужно минусить за такие вопросы, это очень даже правильный вопрос и хорошо что ты его задал.

Comment: вообще-то и относительно крупные проекты (как минимум, учебные) тоже начинается с написания кода. если есть команда на крупный проект, то естественно с макета и описания всех идей: например, проектирование лендинга.

Comment: @S1lllver минусить, может, и не нужно, но тем не менее такие вопросы не соответствуют тематике ruSO

Comment: вопрос про it и программирование, вполне соответствует

Comment: @S1lllver на вопрос невозможно дать однозначный объективный ответ, такие вопросы здесь закрываются и впоследствии удаляются, кроме того он слишком широк и попытка полного ответа на него может занимать толстую книгу на несколько сотен страниц.

Comment: вот аналогичный вопрос, и тут много ответов и никто не жалуется на правила.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/46037/java-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A1-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE?rq=1

Comment: @S1lllver ну так тот вопрос закрыт, всё правильно

Comment: закрыт потому что на него ответили, а не по причине нарушению правил

Comment: @S1lllver там русским по бледно-оранжевому написано, что он закрыт по причине «дубликат». Дубликат он потому, что модераторы и активные пользователи создали отдельные большие вопросы для коллекционирования ресурсов. А создали их, потому что спрашивание учебных ресурсов не является тематикой ruSO, специально чтобы отмечать дубликатами другие вопросы. Так что тот вопрос закрыт именно по причине нарушения правил. Лишь положительный рейтинг спасает его от автоматического удаления. Кроме того, обратите внимание на дату вопроса.

Comment: Хорошо вы правы, закончим этот бессмысленный спор.

Comment: этож как нужно было изучать джаву 2 года, чтобы задавать такие вопросы...

Comment: @S1lllver здесь не бывает "закрыт, потому что ответили", т. к. на хороший вопрос могут поступить ответы и получше. А закрытие, в сущности, запрет на оставление новых ответов, по различным причинам (на вопрос в нынешнем виде хорошо ответить невозможно, или вопрос уже был, или и вовсе неуместен). Рекомендую почитать справочный центр и/или Мету, чтобы лучше понять, что к чему.

Answer (score 5):

```
1 - Что будет делать программа ?

2 - Зачем она будет это делать ?

3 - Стоит ли тратить на это время ?
```

Если с этим определился то идешь дальше.

> Создаешь структуру папок и файлов, что где будет лежать, где будут
>   храниться изображения, где конфигурационные файлы, где ядро и тд.
>   После того как создал структуру.

1 - Имя программы / Основной Модуль

2 - Делишь Основной модуль на другие модули которые отвечают за различные задачи

3 - Начинаешь Проектирование модулей, берешь тетрадь и ручку.
Рисуешь что и как должно работать, откуда берется имя пользователя.
Как рабатает формы забыли пароль, что куда отправляется и тд.

4 - После проектирования и после того как поймешь как это все должно работать начинаешь разработку, пишешь код.

5 - После разработки всех модулей соединяешь это все вместе и получается хорошо структурированная программа.

Вот Пример :

```
1 - Программа Example / Чат

2 - Основной Модуль Чат 

3 - Подмодуль Регистрация

4 - Подмодуль Вход

5 - Подмодуль Забыли Пароль

6 - Подмодуль Отправить Сообщение

7 - Подмодуль Принять Сообщение
```

> И ВОТ ОНА ! Думаешь Программа уже готова к использованию и к релизу ?
>
> Ничего подобного, наливаешь кофе и занимаешься рефакторингом быдло
>   кода который написал во время разработки, и приводишь его в нормальный
>   и читаемый вид чтобы в дальнейшем программу было реально поддерживать.
>   Успехов и процветания !

Comment: Дабы избавиться от костылей и "быдло кода" во время программирования я и задал такой вопрос, а как вы ответили не подходит к написанию больших проектов.

Comment: Нееее. Сразу все продумать никак нельзя. По ходу работы все станет ясно. И алгоритмы никто не пишет, просто надо начать

Comment: Не забываем про тесты!!!

Comment: Мой ответ не подходит к написанию больших проектов ? Вы удивитесь но мы свой большой проект, соц сеть с искусственным интеллектом пишем и проектируем точно так.
Если это не большой проект, то я прошу прощения за неподходящий для вас ответ.

Answer (score 0):

> Процесс разработки состоит из множества подпроцессов, или дисциплин,
>   некоторые из которых показаны ниже. В модели водопада они идут одна за
>   другой, в других аналогичных процессах их порядок или состав
>   изменяется.
>
> - Анализ требований → Спецификация программного обеспечения
> - Проектирование программного обеспечения
> - Программирование
> - Тестирование программного обеспечения
> - Системная интеграция (System integration)
> - Внедрение программного обеспечения (или Установка программного
>     обеспечения)
> - Сопровождение программного обеспечения

Взято из [статьи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) в википедии.

Рекомендую почитать статьи и книги по современным гибким методологиям разработки
(Scrum, Kanban, etc.), изучить ПО которое используется в тех или иных методологиях(JIRA, Trello, YouTrack, etc.), и системы контроля версий (Git, Mercurial, SVN).

Comment: Вы ознакомились со статьёй?  Опишите, как она поможет автору вопроса.

Comment: Прежде всего статья эта автору никак не навредит. Да и в самой статье есть основной список этапов разработки ПО с ссылками на более детальное описание каждого из них.

Comment: А если адресс ссылки будет изменён или удалён, Ваш ответ станет полностью безполезным. Дайте конкретный ответ на вопрос, можно даже цитировать из материала в ссылке.  Ознакомтесь со [справкой про ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Спасибо. Статьи и книги в ближайшем будущем прочитаю